# Prove that $\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+R_8(x)$ where $|R_8(x)|\leq \frac{x^8}{8!}$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Prove that 
$$\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+R_8(x)$$

where $|R_8(x)|\leq \frac{x^8}{8!}$

Comment: Which formulas for the error term in a Taylor expansion do you know?

Comment: $R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n)}(y)}{n!} x^n$

Comment: Well, when $f(x)=\cos(x)$ what is $f^{(8)}(x)$?

Comment: $f^{(8)}(x)=\cos x$ so I get $|R_n(x)|=|\frac{\cos y}{8!}x^8|\leq \frac{x^8}{8!}$

Comment: @Kasper exactly what you wanted to have

Comment: @DominicMichaelis I should have read some definitions :P ...

Comment: @Kasper Than you learned the most important thing in the first three semesters (i guess some more but i am only in the third semester), want some fancy plots for the taylor series ?

Answer (score 1):

The formula you have is the Taylor polynomial of order 7, use the legendre error term and that $|\cos(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x$.

The second derivative of $\cos(x)$  is $-\cos(x)$ so the eight derivative is $\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:   $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{f^ {(i)}(x)x^i}{i! }$
 $\text if$ $$|f^{n+1}(x)|\le M_{n+1}$$then $$|R(x)|\le \frac{M_{n+1}|x|^n}{(n+1)!}$$

Comment: Sorry but now i don't unterstand your first line anymore. Your second display formula is wrong (you surely meant $|x|^n$ instead of $|x|n$ and the stuff is pretty much the same as mine

Comment: @Dominic Michaelis:R(x) is error term of general form of finite teylor sequence

Comment: yeah i know but you say $f(x)=\sum \dots$ which is wrong as you don't mention the error term

Comment: @Dominic Michaelis :thanks i modify  it